# Exclude category from woocommerce product category list

Tags: php, theme-development, woocommerce-offtopic

I need to exclude the default category created from woocommerce after the plugin is installed. I want that this category is not displayed with the others category on the main shop page that is configured to display category and then the relative products. Is this possible? I will rename it in featured products to use the product inside a slider, this is the only place that will query that category. Any help will be appreciated

Comment: You mean, exclude products in the category in the shop's products list?

Comment: no, I want to exclude a caregory, the default one, from the product archive page where they are listed